# How to change the Dateformat in R?

Tags: r, datetime-format

[image]

I want to change the date format of trendsDataD to that of trendsDataE and also I want to change the chr to numeric inorder to merge them into a single table.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

## you can give a try to this

eg

```
as<- "03-jan"
as<- strptime(as,"%d-%b")
```

it will give

```
"2018-01-03 IST"
```

## now format according to your need

```
as <- format(as.Date(as),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

## output

```
"2018-01-03"
```

Comment: @Mathew Jose Pallippadan, If my answer was able to solve your problem then you may mark it as accepted. Thank you